# I need a two button in view page

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi i need a two button in view page

1. Add to cart Product should be added into cart and it should not redirect to shopping cart
2. Buy now Product should be added into cart and It should redirect to Shopping cart

How to implement this?

Comment: For the first point use ajax call and second point use default magento

Comment: I already had ajax add to cart please check this link (soled by) http://kidsdial.com/peacock-bebe-blocks-set-no-7.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing the phtml file
Add a link there which will redirect you to the shopping cart page
view.phtml can be find in catalog->product->view.phtml